# Why can't I use print in if ternary operator in python?

Tags: python

Why is that invalid

```
print('true') if False else print('false')
```

but this one is not

```
def p(t):
    print(t)

p('true') if False else p('false')
```

Comment: Because you're using Python 2 and `print` isn't a function in Python 2. Add `from __future__ import print_function` to the top of your file. Then it'll behave as you expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python 2, `print` is a statement and therefore cannot be directly used in the ternary operator.

In Python 3, `print` is a function and therefore *can* be used in the ternary operator.

In both Python 2 and 3, you can wrap `print` (or any control statements etc) in a function, and then use that function in the ternary operator.

Comment: I know you understand this, but your answer is confusing.  It's not that *functions* can be magically used in the ternary operator, it's that **expressions** can be used.  **Expression** is an important vocabulary term that the OP should learn.  And the OP is not trying to use a *function* in the ternary operator, but rather a *function application*. (yes, both are expressions, but the OP used only the 2nd)

Answer (score 10):

As has been pointed out (@NPE, @Blender, and others), in Python2.x `print` is a statement which is the source of your problem. However,  you don't need the second `print` to use the ternary operator in your example:

```
>>> print 'true' if False else 'false'
false
```

Comment: Yes, in this case is true. But I generalized my use case. I should point that one "argument" it print and the other is a function. But I understand your point and it makes perfect sense!